# Are SharedPreferences cleared when running npx react-native run-android?

Tags: android, react-native

Are SharedPreferences cleared when running

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Comment: Why would it clear SharedPreferences ? The docs have nothing mentioned like that. If this command uninstalls then installs instead of updating the previously installed app then yes they would get cleared.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are only cleared when an app is uninstalled. If the app is uninstalled as part of an update SharedPreferences will not be cleared. See Gogu's answer here for more details https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213576/when-an-app-is-uninstalled-is-its-sharedpreferences-database-cleared

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if the command I wrote uninstalls the app and then reinstalls it on some occassions. I noticed my SharedPreferences getting cleared randomly and I wondered if I had a bug in my code or that on some occassions it was getting uninstalled and reinstalled.

Comment: It's just ```npx react-native run-android```
Basically the normal command you run when debugging the app.